# Python 2 regex search only for https and export

Tags: python-2.7

I have a List with many Links inside (http and https). Now I just want all URLs with https.

Is there a regex for that? I found only one for both.

The URLs are in "". Maybe this makes It easier?

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: do you have an example of the input list

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

regular expressions are very capable at matching all kinds of strings.
The following example program works as you suggest:

```
import re

links = ["http://www.x.com", "https://www.y.com", "http://www.a.com", "https://www.b.com",]

r = re.compile("^https")
httpslinks = list(filter(r.match, links))

print(httpslinks)
```

This prints out only the https links.
What the regular expression is doing is looking for string that start with https. The hat `^` operator looks for string starting with the following characters, in this case "**https**"

If you are facing a space-delimited string, as you somewhat suggested in the comments, then you can just convert the links to a list using split like so:

```
links = "http://www.x.com https://www.y.com http://www.a.com https://www.b.com"
r = re.compile("^https")
httpslinks = list(filter(r.match, links.split(" ")))
```

You can read more on regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

The part about `list(filter(` is only necessary for `python2.x`, `python3.x` seems to do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks is it also possible without , and []?

Comment: Do you mean if it isn't in a list? like just a string?

Comment: Yes, it's a string or .text.

Comment: ```links = "http://www.x.com" "https://www.y.com" "http://www.a.com" "https://www.b.com"```

Answer (score 0):

Now it works:

Thanks to everyone.

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('copyfromfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

text = text.replace('"Url":', '[<a href=')
text = text.replace(',"At"', '</a>] ')

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    link2 = link.get('href')
    if link2.find("video") == -1:
        link3 = 0
    else:
        f  = open("C:/users/%Username%/desktop/copy.txt", "a+")
        f.write(str(link2))
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
```